# magento Shopping cart is empty when going to checkout

Tags: magento, session

Seem to be having a session issue based on my research but none of the solutions that people say to try seem to change anything.

This problem is only happening in IE and Safari. I add an item to cart, then I Proceed to Checkout which then shows

Shopping Cart is Empty

You have no items in your shopping cart.

Click here to continue shopping.

So far I have set cookie lifetime to 86400. Use SID on frontend to Yes otherwise adding an item to cart will instantly say You have no items in your shopping cart. Validate HTTP_USER_AGENT to yes. I have also tried setting Cookie Lifetime to 0.

Comment: Hello, under System > Configuration section Session validation settings, what options are "yes"? Do you use any FPC-solution?

Comment: Validate HTTP_USER_AGENT, and Use SID on Frontend if I set Use SID to NO this happens when trying to add something to the cart...

Answer (score 1):

Deleting Var/Cache folder solved the problem. I first renamed it, which then created a new cache folder. After that I was able to proceed to checkout. I had a lot of folders inside the cache folder I believe it was mage-0 - mage-i so 0-9 then a-i.

I hope this helps someone else in the future it seems that the backend cache removal isn't removing this cache.

Comment: Well this morning it is happening again... And deleting the var/cache folder this morning is not fixing this like it did last night. What could be going on. This only happens in IE and Safari which makes no sense.

Comment: Commenting out this in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php worked. Not sure if this is default in varien.php or if this was added by a previous dev for some reason. if ($cookie->get(session_name()) == $this->getSessionId()) {
$cookie->renew(session_name());

Comment: Well that only worked for a couple mins... TIL magento is awesome.